# subprocess error message:[Errno 2] in _execute_child raise child_exception

Tags: python, subprocess

In my program I call the command:

```
command_two = 'sfit4Layer0.py -bv5 -fs'
subprocess.call(command_two.split(), shell=False)
```

I am using PyCharm and I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "part2test.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.call(command_two.split(), shell=False)  #writes the summary file
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When walking through my program, it never gets to the program I want it to sfit4Layer0.py, it is getting stuck in subprocess but I am not sure why. Changing the shell=True doesn't do anything helpful either - I don't get these error messages but it does not execute my code properly. Any suggestions would be helpful.

My bash profile:

```
PATH="~/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}"

export PATH PYTHONPATH="/Users/nataliekille/Documents/sfit4/pbin/Layer0:/Users/nataliekille/Documents/sfit4/pbin/Layer1:/Users/nataliekille/Documents/sfit4/pbin/ModLib:/Users/nataliekille/Documents/sfit4/SpectralDB"

export PYTHONPATH

PATH=${PATH}:${PYTHONPATH}

export PATH
```

Comment: Is the script in a directory that is in `$PATH`?

Comment: which script are you talking about exactly? I am trying to edit my bash profile now and it is being finnicky. how would you suggest I write the directory into $PATH ?

Comment: Let's say the script resides in `/home/user/Layer0`, in your `.bash_profile` do: `PATH=/home/user/Layer0:$PATH` (there is no need for the { }, although they don't do any harm).  Note I have used the full hierarchic name.  Then, on the command-line, "source" the file" `. ./.bash_profile`, then run your python program or PyCharm.

Comment: so sfit4Layer0.py is in Layer0 and if you look at my above bash profile, it is in there..

Comment: OK.  In that case, does the script work from the command-line?

Comment: it used to but now it isn't - I think I've messed with the bash profile too much but it matches the installation instructions for this software and there are no syntax errors, it just says "command not found"

Comment: If it won't work from the command-line then it won't work from Python.  Could the error be coming from the script itself?  For example a screwed-up #! line?  For example, using `#! usr/bin/python` could cause it (omitting the leading /)

Answer (score 1):

You've missed [an important part of the `subprocess` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). "If passing a single string *[at the command, rather than a list of strings]*, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments."

So the kernel is compaining because there is not executable with the name `'sfit4Layer0.py -bv5 -fs'`. Should work if you replace the string with (for example) `'sfit4Layer0.py -bv5 -fs'.split()`, or `['sfit4Layer0.py', '-bv5',  '-fs']`.

Comment: I do use split when I call it, which should make it a list, right?

Comment: Yes, it should - sorry, I missed that (you didn't edit the question, right?). Yes, that will make it a list. Have you checked that a) `sfit4Layer0.py` exists on your system `$PATH`? b) Its executable bit(s) is/are set correctly? and c) That it has a "shebang" line such as `#!/usr/bin/env python` so the kernel knows which program to process it with?

Comment: I added my bashprofile along. the program is in the Layer0 directory so shouldn't that suffice?

Comment: Not necessarily. Try a simpler call like `subprocess.call('sfit4Layer0.py')`. If that doesn't work (_i.e._ if it still can't run the program) then the issue is that either the `.py` file isn't executable or  it isn't on the search path.

Comment: what do you mean by "isn't on the search path"? It is confusing because if I run it separately (by making the subprocess.call its own program) or type the command into the terminal it works perfectly - it just won't execute in this code. Also when I did what you suggested above, it simply output "command not found"

Comment: @holdenweb: if the file wasn't executable the message would be something like "Permission denied".

Comment: Just trying to cover all the bases. @alli, what does "making the subprocess.call its own program" mean? Adding `$PYTHONPATH` to your `$PATH`, btw, is rather strange - `$PYTHONPATH` is specifically intended to control imports, not execution. Which directory does `sfit4Layer0.py` actually live in?